# How does an oscilloscope synchronize its screen refresh to the waveform?

Tags: oscilloscope

Say I am using a DSO to measure a waveform whose frequency is on the order of megahertz.  I am certain that my DSO cannot refresh its screen that quickly, but it is obviously possible to stabilize a portion of the wave.  For instance, I can display a sine wave from a frequency generator and view a single period of the wave, which would correspond to a 1 microsecond snapshot if the frequency is 1MHz.

So my question is: what is the scope doing behind the scenes to ensure that it is stabilizing the waveform?  How much information gets rejected, and how does that happen?  How is this different for analog scopes without digital control?

Comment: You are completely mixing up different things here. The oscilloscope is sampling the signal, building the appropriate picture in its memory and then displaying this picture on the screen. That's it. There is no relation whatsoever between the signal frequency and the screen refresh rate.

Comment: On analog scopes, there is no memory between the input signal and the displayed wave. Refresh frequency depends directly on the input signal. On DSOs, the screen is just an ordinary LCD screen with fixed refresh rate (around 60Hz). The waveform is stored in some transient memory.

Comment: I think you might really be asking how an oscilloscope trigger works to make sure that the waveform appears stable.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @TEMLIB I think on the older CRT scopes the signal was drawn not by scan lines, but directly by the electron ray deflection, so refresh rate would not be relevant in this case too (well, not in the same sense).

Comment: @Theodore yes, I believe that is what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a digital scope, the capture and the display is mostly decoupled.

For your example of the whole capture period being 1us long, the scope will trigger, capture the whole waveform into the buffer, and then display the buffer to the screen. Then it will retrigger sometime later, capture that, and display that. The refresh rate of the screen isn't really relevant, except in relation to how often the scope can show you a new waveform. It's up to the trigger circuit (and the user adjusting the trigger settings) to make sure that the trigger occurs at the same point in the waveform each time, so that successive triggers show a stable picture.

If you use a slower timebase (say, 100ms/div), then the scope can start pulling samples out of the buffer and displaying them on screen before the whole capture is done, so that you can see the waveform "as it happens". But the samples are still flowing *into* the buffer at a nice constant rate, and again, the refresh rate of the screen doesn't really matter.

For an analog scope, things are pretty different. There *is* no refresh rate, the timebase generator controls the horizontal deflection, the incoming waveform controls the vertical deflection, the trigger gets the party started, and phosphor persistence keeps things on screen for long enough for you to see a whole waveform at once. Each time the trigger fires, the beam starts moving from the left of the screen to the right at a controlled rate, wiggling up and down as it goes... and of course the trigger circuit won't let it start over at the beginning before it gets to the end.